# web scraping coping from web and adding metadata

Tags: web, web-scraping, copy

I would like to download data from the [link](http://apps.occ.gov/EASearch/Search/Cards?Search=&StartDateMinimum=01%2F01%2F2015&StartDateMaximum=02%2F12%2F2018&TerminationDateMinimum=&TerminationDateMaximum=&Category=&Sort=StartDateDescending&AutoCompleteSelection=&CurrentPageIndex=0&ItemsPerPage=1000&ShowTerminatedActionsOnly=false&ShowActiveOnly=false&view=Table&IsAdvanced=true). The data has two options table view and card view. Card view has `Action type` columns that is not present in the table view. How could I add `action type` to table view?

The link provides options to download the data in different formats. When i download the data it provides only tabular format data. `card view' data is not available to download.

Comment: I can see action type column in table view as abbreviations. CSV output format also contains action type column. Please edit the question, add a screenshot with source data, and expected output for that screenshot. What environment /programming language do you use? Check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The link provided download data in different formate. The data are same as card view and tabular view except for pdf download link. If you require PDF file then use R or Python language to generate link and download at a single click.